# Trying to use linq to search based on table with hierarchical data

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities, hierarchical-data

**Duplicate** [many times over](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[entity-framework]+hierarchical) (and also [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[entity-framework]+hierarchy))

I have a table called Types that has the following columns.

ID
Level
Name
ParentID (The ID of the parent row)

and a table called ParentObject which has the following columns.
ID
TypeID

there are 4 different level (possibly to be expanded to more).

So if I had

ID: 1
Level: 0
Name: Level0
ParentID: null

ID: 2
Level: 1
Name: Level1
ParentID: 1

ID: 3
Level: 2
Name: Level2
ParentID: 2

ID: 4
Level: 3
Name: Level3
ParentID: 3

ID: 5
Level: 4
Name: Level4
ParentID: 4

In the ParentObject table I store the tree by just storing the lowest level ID.  So if the ID i have is 4, I know that the tree actually goes Level0 -> Level1 -> Level2 -> Level3

Basically, I need to be able to search all objects for a certain Type, or Type Level 2 for example in a linq statement.

Say that the TypeID stored in the ParentObject table is 4, so Level3.

But I actually want to search for all ParentObjects where the Level 2 type has an ID of 3.

What would be the best way to do this since the id stored could be a level1 or a level2, etc.?

Preferably in one linq statement if possible.

Comment: I could show you how in stored procs with a Common Table Expression... not sure about linq tho :'(

Answer (score 0):

In SQL (MS SQL Server 2005+) you could use a [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to implement recursion. LINQ doesn't support CTE. A couple of work arounds would be one to create the stored procedure and map it as a method to your Data Context.

Another solution would be to write the SQL directly in your C# code and have LINQ execute it. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399403.aspx).

Or you could write a bit of C# code that selects from your data until there isn't any more parent ID's. A rough example would be...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
         IList<Data> data = new List<Data>();

        data.Add(new Data() { ID = 1, ParentID = 0, SomeData = "Example" });
        data.Add(new Data() { ID = 2, ParentID = 1, SomeData = "Another Example" });
        data.Add(new Data() { ID = 3, ParentID = 2, SomeData = "Example three" });
        data.Add(new Data() { ID = 4, ParentID = 3, SomeData = "Last example" });

        IList<Data> results = new List<Data>();

        Int32 parentID = 2;

        while (parentID > -1)
        {
            results.Add(
                data.Where(x => x.ParentID == parentID).Single()
            );

            parentID--;
        }
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public Int32 ParentID { get; set; }
    public String SomeData { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps!